Software/DSP based differential and common emulation in ADC
A differential op amp amplifies the difference and rejects the common signal.
Can you create this effect in ADC (2 or more ADC, not timed multiplexed) and firmware/software by using say channel $A$ and $B$. For example, if you subtract the signal of channel $A$ from the signal of channel $B$, you will automatically cancel any signal $C$ that is common to both: $A = A_{0} + C$, $B = B_{0} + C$, $B - A = B_{0} + C - A_{0} - C = B_{0} - A_{0}$.
If you don't need any programmable gain amplifier in ADC because the input can be mapped correctly to say the 24-bit ADC 250mV range. Then is the above used? How does it compare to a real op amp inaccuracies?
If yes. How are the accuracies compared to a real op amp? Why doesnt it seem to be common (pun unintended)?

Please clarify what you mean by channel A and channel B; are they the synchronously sampled signals from two ADC’s or time multiplexed?

2 or more ADC. not time multiplexed.


Can you create this effect in ADC

Theoretically yes, but you won't find it in practice.

Then is the above used?

No

How does it compare to a real op amp inaccuracies?

It's not as good, that is why it's not being used. In fact most "better" ADC have differential inputs for that very reason. The differential amplifier is already build in and highly optimized for this specific environment and application. That's a) cheaper and b) better than using two separate ADCs.
The noise rejection you get by using balanced signals depend a lot on how "good" your difference is. If you want to have a common mode rejection of, say, 50 dB, the paths need to be gain matched to 0.03 dB. That's a lot easier to do on a single small piece of silicon vs two different signal chains with their individual amps,  Rs and Cs, ADC chips etc.

What if the signal would be mapped directly to the ADC without any gain? Actually there is a product that does it.  see: https://www.gtec.at/product/ghiamp/      "Bipolar derivations can be calculated by the DSP to work with a very high CMRR" It has a sensitivity of 8,57 nV / +/- 340 mV  where all signal is directly mapped to ADC without using gain. So you think it can work if there is no requirement to be gain matched?

@Jtl it still is an issue of solely how well gain matched are your two ADC.  Even if it's two inputs to the same stereo or 4-input ADC, the multiple inputs may have slight variations in scaling going it that you don't worry about for two separate signals.  But your CMRR will be shit if the gain matching isn't nearly perfect.

Even without any gain. Why would slight variations in input produces effects of gain? I have the 16 channel g.USBamp where such common mode rejection between 2 ADC is what it does in the bipolar mode. What kind of signal can I use to actually test it? I'm imagining 2 equal sine wave at the 2 ADC and the deduction of the signal would produce a flat line.  If it's flat line. It's good or still suffering from bad CMRR? What is the way to test for CMRR in the 2 ADCs where the signals are deducted by DSP or software?

Well, you might see this in practice if the two signals are separated by some barrier that's more expensive to overcome than buying sufficiently better ACDs.

//"What is the way to test for CMRR in the 2 ADCs where the signals are deducted by DSP or software?"// - - - - - same as for an op-amp diff amp.  Connect the two inputs together and feed them the same damn signal.  Then in the DSP code, subtract one of the inputs from the other and see how close to zero you get.

see related separate questions at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/94177/can-gain-calibration-be-used-in-pc-in-the-outputs-of-2-adcs

One advantage of the dual-ADC approach is that a relatively trivial continuous background-cal algorithm can eliminate the gain mismatch in the digital domain.

How does the Algorithm work? maybe gtec make use of it. Their bioamplifiers were used by hundreds of top companies. It is supposed to be the standard where others compared it to.

Call the two adc signal x1(k) and x2(k), and introduce a slowly-varying gain adjustment variable g(k). The output y(k) will be formed from g(k)x1(k)- x2(k).   The update equation for g(k) should be; g(k)=g(k-1) + alpha (g(k)*x1(k)- x2(k)), where alpha is a small constant that determines the convergence speed

Correction, update equation for g(k) should be; g(k)=g(k-1) -alpha* (abs(g(k)*x1(k)) - abs(x2(k)). For this to work there must be no DC offset in the converters. Practically, this means you should use a 1st-order high pass filter on each channel before trying the algorithm suggested above.

see related separate questions at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/94177/can-gain-calibration-be-used-in-pc-in-the-outputs-of-2-adcs

The g.USBamp only has 7th and 8th order firmware Butterworth filter. Can 7th and 8th order work too and not just 1st order high pass filter to avoid DC offset?
